# jQuery color plugin

Tags: jquery, colors, background, jquery-animate, jquery-color

I'm very new to jQuery. I created a little script to animate color background of a DIV and border color of another DIV in loop.
I used the jquery color plugin and the script works! (Unbelievable)

The problem is that my script is veeery slow, and I have problem with page loading (especially with IE)
This is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {                   
      spectrum();
      function spectrum(){
      $('#rt-main').animate( { backgroundColor: "#aeff00" }, 5000);
      $('#rt-main').animate( { backgroundColor: "#ff6c00" }, 5000);
      $('#rt-main').animate( { backgroundColor: "#0086b6" }, 5000);
      $('#rt-main').animate( { backgroundColor: "#00a4a8" }, 5000);
      $('#rt-main').animate( { backgroundColor: "#d43795" }, 5000);
      $('#rt-main').animate( { backgroundColor: "#ffd200" }, 5000);
      $('#rt-header').animate( { borderTopColor: "#aeff00" }, 5000);
      $('#rt-header').animate( { borderTopColor: "#ff6c00" }, 5000);
      $('#rt-header').animate( { borderTopColor: "#0086b6" }, 5000);
      $('#rt-header').animate( { borderTopColor: "#00a4a8" }, 5000);
      $('#rt-header').animate( { borderTopColor: "#d43795" }, 5000);
      $('#rt-header').animate( { borderTopColor: "#ffd200" }, 5000);
      spectrum();
    }

  });   
</script>
```

I'm sure there a better way to do the same thing.
Here you can see a demo. (Doesn't work in IE)

Answer (score 1):

The major problem is your timing is set to 5 seconds, and you're changing the background for the same 2 elements (in this demo) 5-times before their even done animating once.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Edit:

Try this:

```
var i = 0;
var colorArray = ["#aeff00", "#ff6c00", "#0086b6", "#00a4a8", "#d43795", "#ffd200"];

function changeColor(element,element2,color)
{
    $(element).animate( 
    { 
        backgroundColor: color 
    }, 5000, function(){
        if(i<=colorArray.length)
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            i=0;
        }
        changeColor(element,element2,colorArray[i]);
    });

    $(element2).animate( 
    { 
        borderTopColor: color 
    }, 5000});


}

changeColor('#rt-main', '#rt-header', colorArray[i]);
```

Comment: I want to change the 6 colors in loop in both div

Comment: In the example above, you call `changeColor('#rt-main', colorArray[i]);` which you could also do for `#rt-header` if you wanted.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!It works great for background of #rt-main, but i need also to change the border top color of #rt-header at same time.

Comment: Thanks!! I added the "if..." part also to element2 to works. Thanks again

Comment: If that solves your issue, please mark the problem as solved.  Happy to help.